# How to generate encrypted password from Oracle 12 c to connect with JDBC

Tags: java, database, oracle, encryption, jdbc

How to generate encrypted password from  Oracle 12 c to connect with JDBC ?

Client does not want to share password! He can share only encrypted passwords, but he does not know how to generate the password so I can connect.
thanks

Comment: Are they wanting to connect via SSL? https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12517_01/back_office/pdf/141/html/pos_sg/appendix_jdbc_oracle.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They will have to give you the password if you need to connect to the Database. Even if they give you a wallet containing the password there are ways to extract the password out of it. Another option would be to create a database user that can connect through a certificate through an SSL connection but that has a number of configuration steps that are described in the Oracle documentation. The user has to be created like this `create user sslclient identified externally as 'CN=client,C=US'` where `'CN=client,C=US'` is the distinguished name. Then a valid certificate for this distinguished name has to be created and you can use it to connect from JDBC-thin. A simpler approach would be to create a regular database user for you, give you the password, and then remove the user when you're done.